# How does SQOOP decide the data split, when MYSQL has records like this?

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hdfs, sqoop

```
select * from EMP_TEST order by EMPNO asc;
+------------+-------+----------+------+-------------+------+------+--------+
| EMPNO      | ENAME | JOB      | MGR  | HIREDATE    | SAL  | COMM | DEPTNO |
+------------+-------+----------+------+-------------+------+------+--------+
| 6765423233 | WARD  | SALESMAN | 7698 | 22-FEB-1981 | 1250 |  500 |     30 |
| 6767891234 | WARD  | SALESMAN | 7698 | 22-FEB-1981 | 1250 |  500 |     30 |
| 6767891236 | WARD  | SALESMAN | 7698 | 22-FEB-1981 | 1250 |  500 |     30 |
| 7767891234 | WARD  | SALESMAN | 7698 | 22-FEB-1981 | 1250 |  500 |     30 |
| 8767891230 | WARD  | SALESMAN | 7698 | 22-FEB-1981 | 1250 |  500 |     30 |
| 8767891233 | WARD  | SALESMAN | 7698 | 22-FEB-1981 | 1250 |  500 |     30 |
| 9765423233 | WARD  | SALESMAN | 7698 | 22-FEB-1981 | 1250 |  500 |     30 |
| 9767891234 | WARD  | SALESMAN | 7698 | 22-FEB-1981 | 1250 |  500 |     30 |
```

- How does the split be calculated in my case, if i refer to the below example?*

For example:
Assume: min = 0, max = 400, no_of_mappers = 4
split_size = (400 – 0)/4 = 100

So, splits: [0, 100), [100, 200), [200, 300), [300, 400]

Comment: Your "Example" looks correct. What's your actual question/doubt?

Comment: Thanks facha, the tabular format I listed has primary key as EMPNO. Considering the fact that I am not specifying mappers while an import, it should take 4 by default. I want to understand how my data is split, if my EMPNO column looks like this. The 'example' simply had uniform data, hence the splits are easy to calculate. But I don't understand how the data gets split in case of the MySQL snippet I added.

Comment: It will do exactly the same. It will get min and max of the primary key column and separate the range into 4 equal parts. First mapper will get the rows from min until min+(max-min)/4*1, the second one will get rows from min+(max-min)/4*1 until min+(max-min)/4*2, etc... You get the idea. If most of your rows fall into the first interval, then the first mapper will do most of the work. Sqoop won't do anything "smart" about skew you data might have.